# "Not a valid command: views" - trying to render view from console

Tags: scala, playframework

I've created a new project with:

```
snowch$ activator new twitter-stream play-scala-2.4
snowch$ cd twitter-stream
```

I've then opened the console:

```
snowch$ ./bin/activator
```

Followed by compiling:

```
[twitter-stream] $ compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 17-Jun-2017 09:27:38
```

I've then attempted to render a view:

```
[twitter-stream] $ views.html.index.render("Hello World")
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: views
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: views (similar: digest, test, less)
[error] views.html.index.render("Hello World")
[error]      ^
```

My app folder looks like this:

```
snowch$ tree app/
app/
├── controllers
│   └── Application.scala
└── views
    ├── index.scala.html
    └── main.scala.html
```

The view looks like this:

```
snowch$ cat app/views/index.scala.html
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @play20.welcome(message)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you should be able to do it from the scala console, not the sbt console. To enter the scala console, just type `console` in the sbt console, and then try to call your `views.html.index.render("Hello World")`.

On the other hand, you could just display this view in the browser.

To do this, you need to start the Play application server, by executing the `run` command in the activator console. After a while, it will say, in green letters, something like "application started".

Then, you can open your view in the browser, by opening http://localhost:9000/index.html, or just http://localhost:9000